# Matlab coder: How to force a variable to have variable :inf size

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-coder

I can't find how to force Matlab coder to make a parameter size be variable rather than fixed.

Here is a MCVE:

Function code:

```
function [sz] = my_varsize(x)
    sz = length(x);
end
```

Sample main program used in Matlab coder:

```
samp = 100;
x = zeros(1,samp);
sz = my_varsize(x);
display(sz);
```

Then, Matlab coder generates C/C++ code where x size is (1x100).

I can manually change the variable size from `1x100` to `1x:Inf` from the GUI, this works fine, but I'd prefer Matlab coder to do it automatically. I tried to add `coder.varsize('x',[1,inf]);` and `coder.typeof(x,[1,inf]);` both in the function and in the main program, but none had the expected behaviour.

---

Edit: Based on Ryan comment, I tried to call my_varsize with different objects of different sizes to see if Matlab realizes then that this should use a variable size:

```
samp = int64(round(rand()*100));
x = zeros(1,samp);
sz = my_varsize(x);
display(sz);

samp = int64(round(rand()*100));
x = zeros(1,samp);
sz = my_varsize(x);
display(sz);
```

Then, generated code uses a variable size of 61 (biggest result of the two `rand()` calls) `[1,:61]`, while I need `[1,:inf]` so that my generated C/C++ code can be used with any input!

Comment: I assume MATLAB is trying to be smart and optimize your code. I wonder if there is something in the coder parameters to avoid this

Comment: `coder.varsize` seems to be meant for that, but I cannot make it work!

Comment: From your example code, `x` only ever has size 100. So MATLAB Coder just discarded the `coder.varsize`. If you include that array in a more complex example that actually assigns a non-constant or varying size it'll stick. Otherwise, can you expand your example to show what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @RyanLivingston: See my edit, even with many inputs, it does not use `:inf` as upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're using the auto-define capability in the MATLAB Coder app. What that does is to run the script you provided and monitor inputs to your function `my_varsize`. Let's take a concrete example:

**function `my_varsize.m`**

```matlab
function [sz] = my_varsize(x)
    sz = length(x);
end
```

**test script `my_varsize_tb.m`**

```matlab
samp = 20;
x = zeros(1,samp);
sz = my_varsize(x);
display(sz);

samp = 37;
x = zeros(1,samp);
sz = my_varsize(x);
display(sz);
```

Here, `my_varsize_tb` is run and Coder detects 2 calls to `my_varsize`. The first takes a `1-by-20` double array. The second takes a `1-by-37` array. So it computes that the input must be `1-by-:37`. Since you can only make a finite number of calls this way, the input will only ever be determined to have a finite upper bound.

You can then tweak the size to be `1-by-:Inf` in the Coder App:

[image: Coder app varsize]

**More info**

There is a command-line function giving the same behavior that you might be using:

```matlab
>> t = coder.getArgTypes('my_varsize_tb','my_varsize')

t =

  1×1 cell array

    {1×1 coder.PrimitiveType}

>> t{1}

ans = 

coder.PrimitiveType
   1×:37 double
```

You can similarly tweak that size:

```matlab
>> inputType = coder.resize(t{1},[1,Inf])

inputType = 

coder.PrimitiveType
   1×:inf double
>> codegen my_varsize -args inputType
```

to use it with the `codegen` command.

Lastly given that you have a simple function you can just do:

```matlab
t = coder.typeof(1, [1,Inf]);
codegen my_varsize -args t
```

`coder.typeof` takes the first input to determine that it's a real `double` and the size. When you pass a second argument, that overrides the size, producing a `1-by-:Inf` as expected in this case.

Comment: Exactly, I'm using 'auto-define capability'. and I currently tweak the size to `:inf` as you suggest. I'm not running `codegen` as I run the coder from the GUI. Is there no flag in the code I could add to have 'auto-define capability' understand that I want a `:inf` upper bound? That's what I was looking for, I believed it was doable using `coder.varsize` as the doc suggests it (https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/coder.varsize.html): "The declaration instructs the code generator...","...also specifies an upper bound". But I could not make it work.